# bootstrap input-prepend makes two div inline (in a same line),no new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.jss"></script>

<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span>
  <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInput" type="text">
  <span class="add-on">.00</span>
</div>
```

the result is :[image: divs inline]

So,two divs are in the same line.How can i have a new line?
The default sytle of div is block,is that mean when I use `prependedInput` and `appendedInput` ,it will change it to inline?

bootstrap version is 2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see the documentation provided in [**Bootstrap 2.3.2**](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html), it doesn't state that your classes `input-append` and `input-prepend` will be in the same line.

It's just shown for clarity purpose. But will also see that you will get it in a new line when you change it to smaller screen i.e. `col-xs-12`.

Do it be either `<br>` or `col-xs-12`:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.jss"></script>
<form class="bs-docs-example">
  <h4>Using <code>col-xl-12</code></h4>

  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">@</span>
      <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <div class="input-append">
      <input class="span2" id="appendedInput" type="text">
      <span class="add-on">.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<h4>Using <code>&lt;br/&gt;</code></h4>

<form class="bs-docs-example">
  <div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">@</span>
    <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span2" id="appendedInput" type="text">
    <span class="add-on">.00</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why they are in the same line by default, what is intention of the official twitter bootstrap to do so?

Comment: @user6630815, official bootstrap, won't push it to the next line. It's just shown for clarity purpose. Check the edited answer